# Kafka Streams 2.1.1 class cast while flushing timed aggregation to store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to use kafka streams to perform a windowed aggregation and emit the result only after a certain session window is closed. To achieve this I'm using the suppress function.

The problem is that I don't find a way to make this simple test work because when it tries to persist the state I get a class cast exception because it tries to cast Windowed to String.
I have tried to provide to the aggregate function a `Materialized<Windowed<String>,Long,StateStore<>>` but it doesn't type check because it expects the first type to be simply string.

What am I missing here?

kafka version 2.1.1

```java
package test;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.SessionWindows;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.test.ConsumerRecordFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestAggregation {

    @Test
    public void aggregationTest() {
        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, Long> input = streamsBuilder.stream("input");

        input
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
            .aggregate(() -> Long.valueOf(0), (key, v1, v2) -> v1 + v2, (key, agg1, agg2) -> agg1 + agg2)
            .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
            .toStream()
            .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k.key(), v))
            .to("output");

        Topology topology = streamsBuilder.build();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass().getName());

        TopologyTestDriver testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, props);

        ConsumerRecordFactory<String, Long> producer =
            new ConsumerRecordFactory<>("input", Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.Long().serializer());

        testDriver.pipeInput(producer.create("input", "key", 10L));

        ProducerRecord<String, Long> output = testDriver.readOutput("output", Serdes.String().deserializer(), Serdes.Long().deserializer());
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("output: k: {0}, v:{1}", output.key(), output.value()));
    }
}
```

And this is the stacktrace that I get out of it

```
17:05:38.925 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask - task [0_0] Committing
17:05:38.925 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager - task [0_0] Flushing all stores registered in the state manager
17:05:38.929 [main] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager - task [0_0] Failed to flush state store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000001: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.suppress.KTableSuppressProcessor.buffer(KTableSuppressProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.suppress.KTableSuppressProcessor.process(KTableSuppressProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.suppress.KTableSuppressProcessor.process(KTableSuppressProcessor.java:37)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ForwardingCacheFlushListener.apply(ForwardingCacheFlushListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore.putAndMaybeForward(CachingSessionStore.java:179)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore.access$000(CachingSessionStore.java:37)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore$1.apply(CachingSessionStore.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore.flush(CachingSessionStore.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredSessionStore.flush(MeteredSessionStore.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:491)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:443)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:431)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.pipeInput(TopologyTestDriver.java:405)
    at test.TestAggregation.aggregationTest(TestAggregation.java:49)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two option to solve that issue:

1. use `TimeWindowedKStream::aggregate(final Initializer<VR> initializer, final Aggregator<? super K, ? super V, VR> aggregator, final Materialized<K, VR, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized);`
2. use `KStream::groupByKey(final Grouped<K, V> grouped)`

In you case it will be:

Ad 1:

```java
input
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
    .aggregate(() -> Long.valueOf(0), (key, v1, v2) -> v1 + v2, (key, agg1, agg2) -> agg1 + agg2, Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
    .toStream()
    .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k.key(), v))
    .to("output");
```

Ad 2:

```java
input
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long())
    .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
    .aggregate(() -> Long.valueOf(0), (key, v1, v2) -> v1 + v2, (key, agg1, agg2) -> agg1 + agg2)
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
    .toStream()
    .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k.key(), v))
    .to("output");
```

Comment: Thank you @wardziniak ! I've accepted the answer it actually fixes the ClassCastException. 
It's not clear to me what's happening now, how can the streams know about the status of the window if it is going to store the key as String instead of Windowed? 

I'm not able to test the full behaviour with the testDriver, not sure if it's the testDriver that doesn't support it; will test it on a more realistic environment and update this post if needed.

Comment: You can find full explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110206/kafkastreams-getting-window-final-results/54115693#54115693

Answer (score 1):

To make this work with TopologyTestDriver, you would need to advance the clock time, which it seems has no effect on the Suppress step. A workaround is to allow your test to override the Suppress config with a setting like this:

```
Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ZERO, BufferConfig.unbounded())
```

Comment: Is it not enough that the timestamp extractor advances the time according to the next message?
I am not getting the expected 'suppress behavior' with TopologyTestDriver but it looked to me as the stream time adjusts correctly by the TimestampExtractor, because prevTimestamp's value seems to be correct. Is there another reason/bug that causes TopologyTestDriver not to support suppress?