# Kafka stream groupByKey not working for count()

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to generate count based on keys, using the below code, this code is based on the word count example. Strangely if the mapValues function returns on a String then the groupBy works as mentioned in the commented line, but when I send a keypair of String as key and GenericRecord as value.

```
final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();

final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url","http://localhost:8081");

stringSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true); // `true` for record keys
final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
                valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // `false` for record values

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, GenericRecord> textLines =
                  builder.stream("ora-query-in",Consumed.with(stringSerde, valueGenericAvroSerde));


final KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines       
                        .mapValues(new ValueMapperWithKey<String, GenericRecord, KeyValue<String, GenericRecord>>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public KeyValue<String, GenericRecord> apply(String arg0, GenericRecord arg1) {

                                        return new KeyValue<String, GenericRecord>(arg1.get("KEY_FIELD").toString(),arg1);
                                        }
                                    })

            //                      .groupBy((key, value) -> value) //THIS WORKS if value is STRING
            //                      .groupBy((key, value) -> key) //DOES NOT WORK EITHER
                                    .groupByKey() //THIS does nothing
                                    .count();
wordCounts.toStream().to("test.topic.out",Produced.with(stringSerde, longSerde));
```

Am I missing something in configuration

```
streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the code not compile? Does it fail with a runtime exception? What is the error message? Or does it compute the wrong result? If yes, what is expected and what observed result?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I added a selectKey before groupBy, I was confusing keyPairValue with Key of Stream itself

Answer (score 0):

You haven't write what exactly is wrong but it seems it is an issue with `Serialization`

You can use:

- `KStream::groupBy(final KeyValueMapper<? super K, ? super V, KR> selector, final Grouped<KR, V> grouped)`.

`someStream.groupByKey((key, value) -> value, Grouped.with(newKeySerdes, valueSerdes)`

- `KGroupedStream::count(final Materialized<K, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized)`

`someGroupedStream.count(Materialized.with(newKeySerdes, valueSerdes)`

Can be same reason like:

- [Kafka Streams 2.1.1 class cast while flushing timed aggregation to store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186727/kafka-streams-2-1-1-class-cast-while-flushing-timed-aggregation-to-store)
- [KafkaStreams: Getting Window Final Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110206/kafkastreams-getting-window-final-results)